# Не работает редирект с сервера go fasthttp router

Tags: http, golang

Есть функция, которая должна редиректить пользователя на другую страницу если он ввел логин и пароль правильно. Пытаюсь сделать редирект с помощью `ctx.Redirect("/сообщения", 308)`. Приходит верный ответ, но браузер не переходит на страницу. В чем может быть проблема? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, после POST запросов браузер не делает автоматический редирект. Решилось проверкой на response.redirected + react-router history push